# Closing a database in SQLite3 without exiting program

Tags: sqlite, visual-studio-code, file-permissions

I'm editing the same databases in two programs. SQLite3 and VScode.

Whenever I make changes in VScode I have to exit sqlite3.exe or I get the "PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process:" error.

I understand why that is. However, I'd like to be able to quickly reopen the databases in sqlite3.exe without having to reopen the program and type (or copy-paste) the file addresses and settings again.

Is there a way to close the database file in sqlite3 so that it can be freely modified by other programs, then quickly reopen it that doesn't require exiting and relaunching the entire program?

All the answers I was able to find only gave advice on how to exit the program. Nothing in .help seemed to do what I wanted either.